# Understanding parameters in an anonymous function (callback example)

Tags: javascript, callback

There is an [example in JavaScriptIsSexy](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) for a simple callback that I'd like to understand a bit better:

```
var friends = ["Mike", "Stacy", "Andy", "Rick"];

friends.forEach(function (eachName, index){
console.log(index + 1 + ". " + eachName); // 1. Mike, 2. Stacy, 3. Andy, 4. Rick​
});
```

In this case, how are the parameters `eachName` and `index` understood to mean the elements of the array (people's names as strings) and index numbers, respectively? Would that have to be specified via arguments in the call that just isn't shown here, but is expected if you want the output shown in the comment?

Comment: It's how the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) callback is defined to accept as parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) works.

You give it a function to call for each element of the array.

That function will be called with the following arguments (in order):

1. the current element
2. the index of the current element
3. the whole array

In your case, you have

```
function (eachName, index)
```

So this means that `eachName` is the current element, `index` is the index and you don't make use of the third parameter.

In addition to these three parameters, you also have the option of having a `this` appear inside of your function. That is specified by an optional second argument to `forEach` (after your callback function).

Comment: don't forget about forEach callback's "fourth argument"; this, which is provided by the 2nd argument to forEach().

Answer (score 2):

Because that is how the `forEach` function is defined, as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach :

> callback is invoked with three arguments:
>
> - the element value
> - the element index
> - the array being traversed

Obviously, the names `eachName` and `index` don't mean anything specially by themselves.  They're meaning is purely positional.  You can call them and use them as whatever you want.  Whatever name you put first will be used as the parameter name for the element value, the 2nd as the element index, and the 3rd as the array.

Even though you're not yet using it, there is also a 3rd parameter that you could declare and use - the entire array - if you want it.  Similarly, if you don't care about the index, you don't need to define it either.

Comment: don't forget about the "fourth argument"; _this_, which is provided by the 2nd argument to forEach().